# AJAX Post stops other application events to fire

Tags: jquery

I have one AJAX/JSON post method to delete my record in client side. When user clicks on the link, the application will prompt user to confirm the action. When user pressed confirm button, the spinner will block the whole screen to prevent any actions before the delete action completes. so when i click **Ok** button, the spinner was not showing rather the prompt dialog struck on the page until completing the delete action. Then, the spinner shows on the page.

**Below is my code.**

```
var val = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these records?");
                if (val) {

                        $("#spinner").show();


                    if (items.length != 0) {
                        if (perm == "True") {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/ItemControl/ItemControl/Del',
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                async: false,
                                data: json,
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    if (data == "S") {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        $('.t-detail-cell').find('.t-refresh').trigger('click');
                                        $('.t-refresh').trigger('click');
                                        showSuccessMessage("Item Successfully Deleted");
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                        }
                      }
                   }
```

Comment: What is `perm` ? And `items`? Is the `success` function even executed? Is `data` from `success` really successfully retrieved?

Comment: @ Kamil T.: perm is my internal permission check. Everything in the AJAX call works fine. except the one for loader.

Comment: Try adding `alert(data)` in the `success:` section and see if it is triggered.

Comment: Yes. The alert prompts with character 'S'.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` - what is that supposed to do? Do you have `e` declared somwhere? what action do you want to prevent?

Comment: For preventing some other postback actions.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, Hope it helps

```
var val = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these records?");
            if (val) {

                if (items.length != 0) {
                    if (perm == "True") {
                       $("#spinner").show();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/ItemControl/ItemControl/Del',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            async: false,
                            data: json,
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data == "S") {
                                  $("#spinner").hide()
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $('.t-detail-cell').find('.t-refresh').trigger('click');
                                    $('.t-refresh').trigger('click');
                                    showSuccessMessage("Item Successfully Deleted");
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                  }
               }
```